# Why was the zero-gravity effect not transferred to the third level in Inception?

Tags: inception

In *Inception*, near the end there are three dream levels. In Level 1, when the van enters freefall, there is zero gravity in level 2.

This means that the members of level 2 experience no gravitational force. At one point in the movie you are shown these members floating in midair.

Why doesn't this carry over to level 3? Our sensory organs (or any sensory organ you devise, for that matter), cannot distinguish between freefall and zero gravity. Shouldn't the zero-G in level 2 cause zero-G in level 3?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/475/why-arent-the-characters-floating-two-levels-down